# Simplest and cleanest way to process multiple (un)checked checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, laravel

I have an email system where subscribers can subscribe to multiple lists. In subscriber edit mode, I have a table where all the lists are listed with checkboxes where the ones the subscriber is subscribed to is checked.

So far so good :)

However, I need to process these checkboxes when the form submits. So far the checkbox code looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lists[]" value="<?= $list->id ?>" />
```

This returns the following data when submitted:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(1) "7"
    [1]=> string(1) "8"
}
```

But here's where the "hard" part. I could always loop the array and add the subscriber to those lists, but the user might already be subscribed to those lists. These IDs are sent even if no checkboxes was manipulated.

What I imagine I could do, is to get all available lists in an array, flag those lists who are unsubscribed and subscribed and ignore those who are not manipulated. The only thing is that this sounds a bit too complicated.

How would you do this? There surely must be an easier way to do this. The bottom line is that I don't want to update subscriptions if they're not manipulated through the checkboxes.

Comment: Can't you just remove all subscriptions and then add the submitted ones?

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` followed by `DELETE WHERE NOT IN...`?

Comment: Depends on your schema. Is a subscription represented by a value (like `subscribed=1`) or by mere existence of a record?

Comment: Might be a weird idea.
You can capture the click or check event using javascript or Jquery . Use hidden field to update the id as a comma seperated value that is append the id with comma for each checkbox operations .

Based on that you can able to know what are all the checkboxes user changed.

Comment: Does it matter if you 're-send' those flags? I can't see why it would.

Answer (score 2):

How I'd solve it is first by creating an array of lists where key would be the id and value would be whatever it's checked (1) or not (0).

Then loop through it to create checkboxes.

And on saving use [array_diff_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to find these that got their value changed. Then save the difference in DB.

Someone suggested using <kbd>INSERT IGNORE</kbd> but it's quite inefficient with large amount of data. Processing in PHP should be much faster (as you need to pull these data from database anyway - to display the checkbxes, so you already have it and there's no real overhead on the database).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your suggestions. I failed to mention that I use Laravel as framework, and they have a function that solves exactly problems like this.

I solved it using the following code:

```
$subscriber = Subscriber::find(Input::get('subscriber_id'));
$subscriber->maillist()->sync(Input::get('lists'));
```

Now this keeps the relations in sync for me :)